# MekaVerse NFT smart contract is using ECDSA, but I don't understand how it works

Tags: solidity, signature, smartcontracts, ecdsa, nft

In the smart contract of MekaVerse I can see these lines to enable a whitelisting, but I don't understand the theory behind it and how I can use it.

```
function mint(uint256[] memory _tokensId, uint256 _timestamp, bytes memory _signature) public payable saleIsOpen {

    uint256 total = totalToken();
    require(_tokensId.length <= 2, "Max limit");
    require(total + _tokensId.length <= MAX_ELEMENTS, "Max limit");
    require(msg.value >= price(_tokensId.length), "Value below price");

    address wallet = _msgSender();

    address signerOwner = signatureWallet(wallet,_tokensId,_timestamp,_signature);
    require(signerOwner == owner(), "Not authorized to mint");

    require(block.timestamp >= _timestamp - 30, "Out of time");

    for(uint8 i = 0; i < _tokensId.length; i++){
        require(rawOwnerOf(_tokensId[i]) == address(0) && _tokensId[i] > 0 && _tokensId[i] <= MAX_ELEMENTS, "Token already minted");
        _mintAnElement(wallet, _tokensId[i]);
    }

}

function signatureWallet(address wallet, uint256[] memory _tokensId, uint256 _timestamp, bytes memory _signature) public view returns (address){

    return ECDSA.recover(keccak256(abi.encode(wallet, _tokensId, _timestamp)), _signature);

}
```

The interesting part that I don't understand is here :

```
address signerOwner = signatureWallet(wallet,_tokensId,_timestamp,_signature);
require(signerOwner == owner(), "Not authorized to mint")
```

And here :

```
function signatureWallet(address wallet, uint256[] memory _tokensId, uint256 _timestamp, bytes memory _signature) public view returns (address){

return ECDSA.recover(keccak256(abi.encode(wallet, _tokensId, _timestamp)), _signature);
```

}

Thank you for your help,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MekaVerse](https://etherscan.io/address/0x9a534628b4062e123ce7ee2222ec20b86e16ca8f#code) contract uses the OpenZeppelin [ECDSA](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.3.3/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol) implementation, specifically its `recover()` function. ECDSA stands for "Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm" and basically, it allows to sign a message using a private key and to check validity of the signature without providing the private key.

The `recover()` function takes 2 arguments in this case: `bytes32` (array of 32 bytes) `hash` of a signed message, and `bytes` (dynamic-length array of bytes) `signature`. Then it validates whether the `hash` and `signature` match according to the ECDSA. If it does, it returns the signer address. If the validation fails, it returns the zero address (`0x0`).

Note that the signature is a result of signing a message using a private key - but it's not the private key.

You can learn more about signing messages in the web3 documentation of the [sign()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign) function. If you're interested in the ECDSA (or cryptography in general) in more depth, the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) shows some basic information and links to other sources.